# dropdownlist not retaining values on submit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Width="110px">
    <asp:ListItem>Test1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Test3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList> 

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" Width="110px">

</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

I am trying to add list items to ddl2 on ddl1.SelectedIndexChanged based on the selected index.

```
ddl2.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select", "-1"))
ddl2.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem("value2", "1"))
ddl2.Items.Insert(2, New ListItem("value3", "2"))

Protected Sub ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ddl2.Items.Clear()


      If (ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0) Then
 ddl2.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select", "-1"))
    ddl2.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem("value2", "1"))
    ddl2.Items.Insert(2, New ListItem("value3", "2"))
End if
End Sub
```

On submit i am unable to retain the selected value of ddl2.

Please help me with suggestions. I have tried using hidden values, still  unsuccessful.

Note: I am using an user control.

Comment: Did you mean all these controls are in a user control?

Comment: Show me your Page_Load methods code.......

Comment: You're adding your items dynamically, not as static members; remember that the HTTP model is stateless -- changes that you make on one page load are not persisted across to the next page load.  You either need to cache your items somehow, or draw all of them from another datasource that you load each time you load the page.

Comment: Yes, all these controls are in user control.  Adrian- I have searched various solutions on Google and in most of the solutions data is retrieved from the database, added dynamically to the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to make Autopostback Property of ddl1 to true.

**Put this in ddl1 select index changed**

```
If ddl1.SelectedValue = "test1" Then
    ddl2.Items.Add("one")
ElseIf ddl1.SelectedValue = "test2" Then
    ddl2.Items.Add("two")
Else
    ddl2.items.Add("three")
End If
```

**put this in button click**

```
Label1.Text = "first : " + ddl1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "Second :" + ddl2.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

I tried this and it works.Alter this according to your requirement

Comment: Wouldn't it have been more straight forward for *you* to go to converter.telerik.com, convert the code and then post it here?

Comment: I am not good in vb.net.Even if i convert i am unaware of synatx errors.He is working in Vb.net.He knows in and out.So i told him to do that.Any Problem.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors even when it's in C#, because none of your `ddl2.Items.Add` calls have the correct case, or semi-colons.  When running it through Telerik's converter it will complain about a lack of EOF, and someone unfamiliar with C# wouldn't know what to look for.

Comment: I fixed and converted to vb.net.Happy now.

Comment: If (ddl1.SelectedIndex = 0) Then
      ddl2.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Please Select", "-1"))
      ddl2.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem("value2", "1"))
      ddl2.Items.Insert(2, New ListItem("value3", "2"))
      End if

Comment: OK. I am working on cascading dropdown list without binding data from the database rather inserting them on SelectedIndex change. After i select a value from ddl2 and submit it, the value is not retained.